# Can Elasticsearch index a site with SAML authentication?

Tags: elasticsearch, saml

We recently moved our intranet from hosting on prem, using Windows Authentication to grant access to the app, to hosting by a 3rd party.  The 3rd party option is using Azure AD to authenticate the user, passing a SAML token to the app.  We've already confirmed that SharePoint Search isn't able to index a site with this type of authentication (which is what we were successfully using when hosted on prem).

I've read Elasticsearch can authenticate using SAML, but I suspect this only means that users can  authenticate to the Elasticsearch app.  What I need is to be able to configure a crawler to impersonate a user and pass a SAML token.  Can somebody confirm if this is possible with Elasticsearch?

Tks

Comment: Elasticsearch does not crawl anything, you need to user another tool to crawl the data and then ingest it into elasticsearch.

Comment: What about the Enterprise Search web crawler? - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/current/crawl-web-content.html#crawl-web-content-manage-crawl

Comment: This is an example of another tool that you need to install and configure independently from elasticsearch.  Also, it [does not support](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/current/web-crawler-faq.html#web-crawler-faq-what-functionality-is-not-supported) crawling websites behind authentication.

Comment: "impersonate a user and pass a SAML token". A SAML token is only valid for a specified time and the site, which would be an SP would need to support IdP initiated SSO as the SAML token would arrive unsolicited from whatever is impersonating a user. If anything else got hold of that SAMLRequest parameter it would be able to login as that user too and do whatever it wants based on that "user's" privileges.

Comment: Thanks @leandrojmp.  The FAQs link you added answers my question.